# ¿Cómo puedo consumir un json con ajax y mostrar los datos con DataTables Plugin de Jquery,?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

estoy intentando consumir una api para luego mostrarlo en una tabla via ajax con DataTables Plugin de Jquery  pero no estoy logrando que la tabla se cargue con los datos

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.md5@1.0.2/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

> este es el script que deberia consumir el json

<script>

$('#tabla').dataTable({
  ajax: {
    cache: true,
    url: `https://my-json-server.typicode.com/AldoArevalo%20/repoaldo/aguinaldo`,
    dataSrc: 'data.results'
  },
  columns: [{
    "data": "AACAA_PADR"
  }, {
    "render": function(v, t, data) {
      return `<img width="100" src="${ data.thumbnail.extension}"/>`;
    }
  }, {
    "data": "AACAA_BANC"
  }, {
    "data": "AACAA_CEDU"
  }]
});
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>


</head>

<body>
<table id="tabla" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: puedes poner que es lo que te regresa tu api, en la petición

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ingresando directamente a la URL proporcionada se obtiene el siguiente resultado:

```
[
  {
    "AACAA_PADR": 12800,
    "AACAA_BANC": 26,
    "AACAA_CEDU": 3524244,
    "AACAA_APOR_AGUI": 5500000,
    "AACAA_CANT_CUOT": 12,
    "AACAA_IMPO_CUOT": 1800000,
    "AACAA_AAMD_LIQU": 1800000,
    "AACAA_TOTA_PAGA": 20000000,
    "AACAA_AAMM_INIC": " 01-01-2010 "
  }
]
```

No hay una propiedad `results`, simplemente se usa `data` y tampoco hay una propiedad `thumbnail`, por lo que se genera un error.

```js
$('#tabla').dataTable({
  ajax: {
    cache: true,
    url: `https://my-json-server.typicode.com/AldoArevalo%20/repoaldo/aguinaldo`,
    // Los datos vienen directamente, se debe dejar cadena vacía
    dataSrc: ''
  },
  columns: [
      {
          "data": "AACAA_PADR"
      },
      /* Omitiendo esta columna se crea la tabla correctamente
      {
          "render": function(v, t, data) {
              // No existe la propiedad thumbnail y eso genera error
              return `<img width="100" src="${ data.thumbnail.extension}"/>`;
          }
      },
      */
      {
        "data": "AACAA_BANC"
      }, {
          "data": "AACAA_CEDU"
      }
  ]
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.md5@1.0.2/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="tabla" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>
```